# nginx how to return timestamp like tengin's unx_time variable

Tags: nginx

Recently we plan to change tengine to nginx, we used $unxi_time variable in tengine, and I didn't find similiar variable in nginx document, any advice on this? thanks

Comment: If the solution is something others might need, please post it as an answer and accept it yourself.  If it's something trivial, please delete this question.  Either way, the issue gets properly resolved for the SO archives.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no solution information to help future searchers.

Comment: sorry, I failed to save the answer before as the connection is bad in my country, I just re-add the answer again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Already solved.

used lua module to return local timestamp

location = /management/timestamp {
   default_type application/json;
   content_by_lua '
        time=os.time();
        ngx.say("{\"timestamp\""..":"..time.."}");
   ';
 }